# How to stop Application.ontime

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro after 1 min of a button click. When
 I press the button again, the first-timer should reset and start from the beginning (macro should not run if I click the button again within 1 minute.it should run only after 1 min of my latest click)

I tried the `application.ontime dtime,"expire", false`, but it is not working. When I tried `application.ontime dtime,"expire", , false` (it is causing error 1004)

```
public dtime as double

private sub commandbutton1_click()
application.ontime dtime,"expire", false
dtime = Now+timevalue("00:01:00")
application.ontime dtime,"expire"
commandbutton2.visible= true

end sub
```

Now after 1 minute of clicking the commandbutton1, macro expire is running (which is to make commandbutton2 invisible). But when I press commandbutton again within 1 min (let's say after 30 sec of the first click), timer keeps running and makes command button 2 invisible in 30 sec. I need timer to reset when the second click. Or please suggest any
alternate method. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: See the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime   It shows how to cancel a scheduled run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public dtime as double

private sub commandbutton1.click()
    'If there's an existing run, cancel it
    If dtime <> 0 then 
        on error resume next 'might already have run, so ignore any error
        application.ontime dtime, "expire", ,false
        on error goto 0      'stop ignoring errors
        dtime=0
    End If

    'schedule next run
    dtime = Now + timevalue("00:01:00")
    application.ontime dtime, "expire"
    commandbutton2.visible = true

end sub
```

Comment: thanks for the comment .will surely try it.but may i know how this works. and mine didn't work.it would have been helpful .

Comment: You can't cancel a non-existing scheduled run: your posted code tries to do that (for the first button click).  And this: `application.ontime dtime,"expire", false` failed because you don't have your `false` argument in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. will try this tomorrow and will let you know

Comment: `If dTime >= Now Then` might work well in this case. You would be able to trim a few lines out of that if block. And the name of the Sub should have an underscore as opposed to a period.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while posting the question. and thanks for your suggestion too